# How to implement code mirror to show hint without CTRL+SPACE

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, codemirror

JavaScript :

```
        $http.get("/getApexBody", config).then(function(response) {
            document.getElementById("saveBtn").disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("cleanBtn").disabled = false;
            $scope.apexClassWrapper = response.data;
            $('#loaderImage').hide();
            if (globalEditor1) {
                globalEditor1.toTextArea();
            }
            setTimeout(function(test) {
                CodeMirror.commands.autocomplete = function(cm) {
                    cm.showHint({
                        hint: CodeMirror.hint.auto
                    });
                };
                var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('apexBody'), {
                    lineNumbers: true,
                    matchBrackets: true,
                    extraKeys: {
                        "Ctrl-Space": "autocomplete"
                    },
                    gutters: ["CodeMirror-lint-markers"],
                    lint: true,
                    mode: "text/x-apex"
                });
                globalEditor1 = $('.CodeMirror')[0].CodeMirror;
            }), 2000
        });
```

This is my JS file, the ctrl-space works fine but I need, to implement autocomplete without any key bindings.

I have even tried this :

```
        $http.get("/getApexBody", config).then(function(response) {
            document.getElementById("saveBtn").disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("cleanBtn").disabled = false;
            $scope.apexClassWrapper = response.data;
            $('#loaderImage').hide();
            if (globalEditor1) {
                globalEditor1.toTextArea();
            }
            setTimeout(function(test) {
                /* CodeMirror.commands.autocomplete = function(cm) {
                    cm.showHint({
                        hint: CodeMirror.hint.auto
                    });
                };*/
                var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('apexBody'), {
                    lineNumbers: true,
                    matchBrackets: true,
                    /*extraKeys: {
                        "Ctrl-Space": "autocomplete"
                    },*/
                    gutters: ["CodeMirror-lint-markers"],
                    lint: true,
                    mode: "text/x-apex"
                });
                editor.on('inputRead', function onChange(editor, input) {
                    if (input.text[0] === ';' || input.text[0] === ' ') {
                        return;
                    }
                    CodeMirror.commands.autocomplete = function(editor) {
                        editor.showHint({
                            hint: CodeMirror.hint.auto
                        });
                    };
                });
                globalEditor1 = $('.CodeMirror')[0].CodeMirror;
            }), 2000
        });
```

But this is not working.
Is there something I am missing here? How can I show live completion hints with codemirror?

I have used show-hints.js , and have modified it a bit to work for "." too. 
Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Use this function to autocomplete codeMirror without <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>.

Set completeSingle to false in the [show-hint.js](https://codemirror.net/addon/hint/show-hint.js)

```
editor.on("inputRead", function(instance) {
    if (instance.state.completionActive) {
            return;
    }
    var cur = instance.getCursor();
    var token = instance.getTokenAt(cur);
    if (token.type && token.type != "comment") {
            CodeMirror.commands.autocomplete(instance);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $http.get("/getApexBody", config).then(function(response) {
            document.getElementById("saveBtn").disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("cleanBtn").disabled = false;
            $scope.apexClassWrapper = response.data;
            $('#loaderImage').hide();
            if (globalEditor1) {
                globalEditor1.toTextArea();
            }
            setTimeout(function(test) {
                /*CodeMirror.commands.autocomplete = function(cm) {
                    cm.showHint({
                        hint: CodeMirror.hint.auto
                    });
                };*/
                var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('apexBody'), {
                    lineNumbers: true,
                    matchBrackets: true,
                    styleActiveLine: true,
                    extraKeys: {
                        ".": function(editor) {
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                editor.execCommand("autocomplete");
                            }, 100);
                            throw CodeMirror.Pass; // tell CodeMirror we didn't handle the key
                        }
                    },
                    gutters: ["CodeMirror-lint-markers"],
                    lint: true,
                    mode: "text/x-apex"
                });
                editor.on('inputRead', function onChange(editor, input) {
                    if (input.text[0] === ';' || input.text[0] === ' ') {
                        return;
                    }
                    //CodeMirror.commands.autocomplete = function(editor) {
                    editor.showHint({
                        hint: CodeMirror.hint.auto
                    });
                    //};
                });
                globalEditor1 = $('.CodeMirror')[0].CodeMirror;
            }), 2000
        });
```

This works, but after entering ".", it does gives methods of that particular variable but after entering few more matching words it again starts showing hints from original set of words.

for eg: `isBatch` and `isAbort` are two methods of System class.

When I start typing Sy... System comes up, then I type ".", them the two methods shows up `isBatch` and `isAbort`, but when I type `isA` instead of showing `isAbort` it starts showing hints from full list of words again.

Is there a way to avoid this too?